# Unable to boot Windows 10 in dual boot

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, windows-10

My grub screen was not showing Windows 10 boot option.
I tried the command:

`sudo os-prober`

but it was not able to detect Windows 10.
Then I made the following changes to 40_custom file

```
menuentry "Windows 10 (loader)"{
    insmod part_gpt
    search --no-floppy --set=root --fs-uuid 8600-6723
    chainloader (${root})/EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi
}
```

I typed the uuid of /dev/sda2 in the above menu-entry and updated the grub file using :
`sudo update-grub`

After restarting the laptop I got Windows 10 (loader) option, but after clicking it it gives error " **invalid signature** ".

Please find below the output of `sudo fdisk -l`  for reference :

[image]

I am also attaching the output of `sudo blkid /dev/sda2` for reference :

[image: sda2]

I also tried Boot-Repair, but it didn't work. [Boot Info Script](http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/tp6CqWkQHJ/)

How can I boot into Windows 10 again?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to boot into Windows after installing Ubuntu, how to fix?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/217904/unable-to-boot-into-windows-after-installing-ubuntu-how-to-fix)

Comment: which answer should I follow

Comment: Try the Rescatux answer and see what happens. Also please upload Boot-Repair's Boot Info Script to Ubuntu Pastebin and post a link to it.

Comment: [link](http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/tp6CqWkQHJ/) Boot Info Script

Comment: How to change boot mode to EFI?

Comment: There is an answer by Boris that tells how to do that at [Unable to boot into Windows after installing Ubuntu, how to fix?](https://askubuntu.com/q/217904/).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/107879/discussion-between-karel-and-jarv-potter).